# How to Create A Dax for RLS?

Tags: powerbi

I have a column named company ID that contains various comapnies with differnet employes in them, I need a DAX Query which will give data A/Q to the Company id, suppose if there are 3 employes inside a company and each of them have a companyid 1 then I they should able to see the reports of each other but they cannot be able to see the reports of comanyid 2 and 3, how this can be achived?

I know I can do this by creating different Roles for each companyid, but how can this be achived if I want this to be built in one particular role???

Comment: You want row level security but aren't willing to make more than one role?

Comment: I want RLS, so that I can filter the data A/Q to the Company_id and all my columns are in one table.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is to implement Dynamic Row Level Security.

**Model:**
[image]

**User Table:** Table that contains user detail along with the field on which we will apply security(here email field).

**Company Table:** Table containing company data .

**User Company Bridge:** Bridge table that contains permission details, for example user x is member of company y and z.

**Company Data Table:** Measures or transaction information of company that is to be filtered.

**Defining RLS(Row Level Security):**

In Modelling -> Manage Roles, create a new role on Email of User Table by this DAX query which returns the email id of logged in user.

```
[Email] = userprincipalname()
```

**Finalizing:**

Go to PowerBI Service -> Dataset -> Security and add users to the roles created.

To test the implementation:

1. Go to Modelling tab of pbix file.
2. Click on View As Roles.
3. Check other User checkbox and put an email ID and also check Profile
   checkbox. 
   Now you can see data filtered.

In this manner it becomes easy to maintain roles and security by just modifying the bridge table that stores all permission details.

Comment: We need to filter out on the basics of company id as the users having companyid 1001 can view all the data of 1001 users, and company id 1002 can view 1002 users details, how can I achieve that kind of scenario

Comment: You can keep user data that you intend to filter in the table 'Company Data' of above answer. If an user can access user data of only one company(i.e., his present company) then you can remove the bridge table and add company ID into User table for joining purpose.

Comment: I want that all the users that belong to 1001 comapny id can see each others data but users beloniging to 1002 comapnyid cant see 1001 company details how to achieve that??